# In my chat application I am getting a response as not authorized

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on chat module in iOS. Getting an response  RECV `<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>`  while authenticating. Can any one suggest me how to overcome this

Comment: That means your password is wrong.

Comment: @xnyhps : actually its working when i give hostname as "local" if I use the ip address of my local pc then in response i am getting not-authorized

Comment: That's likely because your XMPP server considers those different accounts. The hostname is an essential part of an account, just like with email.